# Kendo UI Grid - Export to Excel without server callback

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to export my kendo UI Grid data to excel without any server callback. is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The kendo grid has support for exporting the data to excel natively with no server side support needed.  All you need to do is inlude the 'excel' option in the toolbar and define any options on the excel export you need.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: ["excel"],
        excel: {
            fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx",
            filterable: true,
            allPages: true
        },
```

See the kendo demo for grid exporting to excel
[Kendo Grid Export To Excel](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export).
The reason they include a callback URL is provide legacy browser support.  Documentation on [proxyURL](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-excel.proxyURL) states as such, but isn't needed if you don't have to support Safari, or IE 9 and below.